# How to removes all the elements between the two elements that I select in linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to write a method that takes to elements and delete all element between them and if one of the two elements doesn't exist no element will be removed so I wrote a method but it doesn't work it's stuck in a loop , see the code :

note : 1- I can't call any method .
       2- I can't use use any auxiliary data structure.

```
public void removeBetween(T e1, T e2) {

    if (head == null) {
        return;
    }

    Node<T> tmp1 = current;

    current = head;

    while (current != null) {

        if (current.data.equals(e1)) {
            current = head;
            while (current != null) {

                if (current.data.equals(e2)) {

                    current = head;
                    while (current != null) {

                        if (current.data.equals(e1)) {

                            while (current.data != e2) {

                                if (current == head) {

                                    head = head.next;
                                } else {

                                    Node<T> tmp = head;

                                    while (tmp.next != current) {

                                        tmp = tmp.next;
                                        tmp.next = current.next;
                                    }

                                    if (current.next == null)
                                        current = head;

                                    else
                                        current = current.next;
                                }

                                current = current.next;

                            }
                        }
                        current = current.next;
                    }
                }
                current = current.next;
            }

        }

        current = current.next;

    }

    current = tmp1;

}
```

Comment: too many nested level makes code hard to understand and debug

Comment: you could look for the index of the 2 elements and then use some if states to all remove elements within the 2 given indexes?

Comment: `current` should be a local variable.

Comment: instead of that create a new `linkedlist` and add  those two elements and assign null to the previously created `linkedList` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off starting from scratch. You do not need nested loops at all, let alone five levels of nesting for a task that is, essentially, linear.

Solving the task at hand has a simple plan:

- First, you need to find out if the first element is present. Do it with a single `while` loop. If you reach the end, exit.
- Store the reference to the first element in a separate variable `first`, and continue to finding the second element
- Again, use a separate `while` loop. If you reach the end of the list before finding the second element, exit.
- If you do find the second element, assign it to `first.next`.

That's it, you are done. You could do it with two consecutive `while` loops, or even with a single `while` loop and a couple of `boolean` variables. No nesting is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Made a code, that actually does pretty much what dasblinkenlight already stated.

```
Node<T> current = head; // set the current to head
do {
    current = current.next; // go to next
    if (current == head) { // if it's head, we have reached the end -> return
        return;
    }
} while (!current.data.equals(e1)); // if current.data is wrong, continue loop
Node<T> node1 = current; // match found
do { // do the same again, starting from current, to find the second node
    current = current.next;
    if (current == head) {
        return;
    }
} while (!current.data.equals(e2));
Node<T> node2 = current;
```

Then you can remove the elements between `node1` and `node2`.